# Recieved a malloc error when using 3 inputs but not 2

Tags: c++, class, dynamic, operator-overloading

The code here is supposed to take in dna letter strands/strings ('ATG' + 'CTA' = 'ATGCTA') and be able to combine them and also subtract specific portions from the combined strand. When the user has to input two strands the combination works fine however when there are three the combination seems to get cutoff halfway. Any help is appreciated!
[image]

dnasequence.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#ifndef _DNASEQUENCE_
#define _DNASEQUENCE_
using namespace std;

// class DNASequence 
//
// A class that contains a sequence of nucleotides in the dna_sequence.
// The max_sequence represents the capacity of the dna_sequence.
// A dna_sequence is a c-string of characters that consist only of
// 'A', 'T', 'G', 'C' standing for the 4 nucleotides and ending in a '\0'
// character. Input into the DNASequence is case-insensitive meaning that
// lower or upper case is acceptable, but it should be converted to uppercase
// internally.
//
class DNASequence {
    public:
        DNASequence(); 
        // Assume that the strand is made up of 100 sequences.

        DNASequence(string nucleotides);
        // Assume that the sequence is initialized to the nucleotides string.

        DNASequence(const DNASequence& arg);
        // Copy constructor

        ~DNASequence();
        // Destructor

        DNASequence& operator = (const DNASequence& arg);
        // Assignment operator

        bool operator == (const DNASequence& arg);
        // Equals operator compares the given sequence with the invoking object.

        bool operator != (const DNASequence& arg);
        // Not equals operator compares the given sequence with the invoking object.

        friend DNASequence operator + (const DNASequence& arg1, const DNASequence& arg2);
        // Append the given sequence onto the end of a copy of the invoking object sequence.

        friend DNASequence operator - (const DNASequence& arg1, const DNASequence& arg2);
        // Remove the given sequence from a copy of the invoking object if it exists. Return
        // the modified sequence. If the given sequence is not found, return the
        // invoking sequence unaltered.

        //checks if string is valid
        bool isitvalid(string str);

        friend istream& operator >> (istream& ins, DNASequence& arg);
        // Implement the friend function to read in a nucleotide sequence made up
        // of only the following characters: adenine (A), thymine (T), guanine (G)
        // and cytosine (C). Assume case insensitive but convert to upper internally.

        friend ostream& operator << (ostream& out, const DNASequence& arg);
        // Implement the friend function to write out a nucleotide sequence. No blanks.

        int get_max_sequence() const { return max_sequence; };
        // Accessor for max_sequence.

        char* get_dna_sequence() const { return dna_sequence; };
        // Accessor for dna_sequence.

    private:
        char* dna_sequence; // Dynamic array of char
        int max_sequence; // Maximum number of nucleotides.
};

#endif
```

dnasequence.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <cctype>
#include "dnasequence.h"

using namespace std;

// Assume that the strand is made up of 100 sequences.
DNASequence::DNASequence() 
{
    this->dna_sequence = new char(101); // 100 + null
    max_sequence = 0;
}

// Assume that the sequence is initialized to the nucleotides string.
DNASequence::DNASequence(string nucleotides) 
{
    int i;
    dna_sequence = new char(nucleotides.length()+1);
    for(i = 0; i < nucleotides.length(); i++)
    {
        dna_sequence[i] = nucleotides.at(i);
    }
    dna_sequence[i] = '\0'; // Changed
    max_sequence = nucleotides.length();
    //cout << max_sequence << endl;
}

// Copy constructor
DNASequence::DNASequence(const DNASequence& arg)
{
   this->max_sequence = arg.get_max_sequence();
   this->dna_sequence = new char(this->max_sequence+1);
   int i = 0;
   for (i = 0; i < this->max_sequence; i++)
       dna_sequence[i] = arg.dna_sequence[i];
   dna_sequence[i] = '\0';
}

// Destructor
DNASequence::~DNASequence()
{
    delete dna_sequence;
}

// Assignment operator
DNASequence& DNASequence::operator = (const DNASequence& arg)
{
   this->max_sequence = arg.get_max_sequence();
   dna_sequence = new char(this->max_sequence+1);
   int i = 0;
   for (i = 0; i < this->max_sequence; i++)
   {
       dna_sequence[i] = arg.dna_sequence[i];
   }
   dna_sequence[i] = '\0';
   return *this;
}

// Equals operator compares the given sequence with the invoking object.
bool DNASequence::operator == (const DNASequence& arg)
{
   int i = 0, j = 0;
   while (this->dna_sequence[i] !='\0' && arg.dna_sequence[j]!='\0')
   {
       if (this->dna_sequence[i] != arg.dna_sequence[j])
           return false;           
       i++;
       j++;
   }
   if (this->dna_sequence[i] == '\0' && arg.dna_sequence[j] == '\0')
       return true;
    return false;
}

bool DNASequence::operator != (const DNASequence& arg)
{
   int i = 0, j = 0;
   while (this->dna_sequence[i] != '\0' && arg.dna_sequence[j] != '\0')
   {
       if (this->dna_sequence[i] != arg.dna_sequence[j])
           return true;
       i++;
       j++;
   }
   if (this->dna_sequence[i] == '\0' && arg.dna_sequence[j] == '\0')
       return false;
   return true;
}


// Append the given sequence onto the end of the invoking object sequence.
DNASequence operator + (const DNASequence &arg1, const DNASequence &arg2)
{
   DNASequence temp = arg1;
   if (arg1.get_max_sequence() == 0)
       return arg2;
   if (arg2.get_max_sequence() == 0)
       return arg1;

   temp.max_sequence = arg1.get_max_sequence() + arg2.get_max_sequence();
   temp.dna_sequence = new char(temp.max_sequence + 1);
   //cout << temp.max_sequence;
   int i = 0;
   for (int j = 0; j < arg1.get_max_sequence(); j++)
   {
       temp.dna_sequence[i] = arg1.dna_sequence[j];
       i++;
       //cout << i << endl; debug line
   }
   //i++; // changed

   for (int j = 0; j < arg2.get_max_sequence(); j++)
   {
       temp.dna_sequence[i] = arg2.dna_sequence[j];
       i++;
       //cout << i << endl; debug line
   }
   temp.dna_sequence[i] = '\0'; // changed to i + 1
   return temp;
}

// Remove the given sequence from the invoking object if it exists. Return
// the modified sequence. If the given sequence is not found, return the
// first argument sequence unaltered.
DNASequence operator - (const DNASequence &arg1, const DNASequence &arg2)
{
    DNASequence temp = arg1;
   if (arg1.get_max_sequence() == 0)
       return arg2;
   if (arg2.get_max_sequence() == 0)
       return arg1;

   temp.max_sequence = arg1.get_max_sequence() - arg2.get_max_sequence();
   temp.dna_sequence = new char(temp.max_sequence + 1);
   int i = 0;
   for (int j = 0; j < arg1.get_max_sequence(); j++)
   {
       temp.dna_sequence[i] = arg1.dna_sequence[j];
       i++;
   }
   for (int j = 0; j < arg2.get_max_sequence(); j++)
   {
       temp.dna_sequence[i] = arg2.dna_sequence[j];
       i++;
   }
   temp.dna_sequence[i] = '\0';
   return temp;
}

// check if string is valid
bool DNASequence::isitvalid(string str) 
{
   // Check the string for characters 'A', 'a', 'T', 't', 'G', 'g', 'C', 'c'
   // return false if any characters in the string are different. You can
   // use any means you like, remember what we did with palindrome code to
   // avoid a big if statement.
   bool valid = false;
   for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
   {
       if (str[i] != 'A' && str[i] != 'a' && str[i] != 'T' && str[i] != 't' && str[i] != 'G' && str[i] != 'g' && str[i] != 'C' && str[i] != 'c')
           return false;          
   }
   return true;
}

// Implement the friend function to read in a nucleotide sequence made up
// of only the following characters: adenine (A), thymine (T), guanine (G)
// and cytosine (C). Assume case insensitive but convert to upper internally.
istream& operator >> (istream& ins, DNASequence& arg)
{
     // Read in a string and use the validate function above to ensure that
   // the string has only nucleotides and convert them all to upper case.

   string str;
   ins >> str;
   if (arg.isitvalid(str))
   {
       arg.max_sequence = str.length();
       arg.dna_sequence = new char(str.length()+1);
       int i = 0;
       for (i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
       {
           arg.dna_sequence[i] = toupper(str[i]);
       }
       arg.dna_sequence[i] = '\0';
   }
   return ins;
}

// Implement the friend function to write out a nucleotide sequence. No blanks.
ostream& operator << (ostream& out, const DNASequence& arg)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < arg.get_max_sequence(); i++)
   {
       out << arg.dna_sequence[i];
   }
   out << endl;
   return out;
}
```

dna_main.cpp

```
/*
 * Test driver for DNAStrand with DNASequences
 * 
 *
 *
 */
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include "dnasequence.h"

using namespace std;

// int main()
//
// Implements the driver for the DNAStrand testing using DNASequences.
//
int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    int n;
    char rerun;
    // Implement your test functions here.

    //greeting 
    cout << "Welcome to CRISPR!" <<endl;
    cout << endl;
    do
    {


    // 1. Start a do-while loop that spans the rest of the instructions.

    // 2. Ask the user to enter the number of DNASequences needed for the CRISPR application.
        cout << "Enter the number of DNA sequences needed: ";
        cin >> n;

        // 3. Either declare a vector of DNASequence or a dynamic array where the user enters the number of elements.
        vector<DNASequence>DNA(n); //?

    // 4. In a for-loop, read in a DNASequence for each element in the array using >> operator.
        for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
         {
             cout << "Processing DNA sequence #" << i + 1 << endl;
             cout << "Enter the elements in sequence #" << i + 1 << ": ";
             cin >> DNA[i];  
         }
         /*
         cout << DNA[0];
         cout << endl;
         cout << DNA[1];
         cout << endl;
         DEBUG LINES
         */

    // 5. Declare a DNASequence called big_strand and add each element in the array to big_strand in a for-loop.


            DNASequence big_strand;

            for(int x = 0; x < n ; x++)
            { 
                big_strand = big_strand + DNA[x];
            }

    // 6. Print the final big_strand after the loop using the << operator.

        cout << "The contents in the big strand is: ";
        cout << big_strand;

    // 7. Declare two variables: one for a small sequence of bad_dna and one to hold the clean_strand.
    // NOTE: Make sure that clean_strand is set directly to big_strand when declared.

        DNASequence bad_dna;
        DNASequence clean_strand = big_strand;

        // 6 a. Test == operator
        cout << "Checking == operator ... " << endl;
        if(big_strand == clean_strand)
            cout << "Functioning properly\n";

        // 6 b. Test != operator
        cout << "Checking != operator... " << endl;
        if (big_strand != bad_dna)
            cout << "Functioning properly\n";



    // 8. Ask the user to enter the bad DNASequence to remove from big_strand and put it in the bad_dna variable.

        cout << "Enter a bad DNASequence to remove from big_strand: ";
        cin >> bad_dna;

    // 9. In a do-while loop add the following lines

        // 9 a. set the big_strand to the clean_strand
        // 9 b. subtract the bad_dna from big_strand and put the result in clean_strand
        do
        {
            big_strand = clean_strand;
            clean_strand = big_strand - bad_dna;
            cout << clean_strand;
        }while(clean_strand != big_strand);

    // 10. Use clean_strand != big_strand as the while condition so that it loops until the big_strand is clean.

    // 11. Print the clean_strand as you go and the final result.

        cout << "The contents in the clean strand is: " ; 
        cout << clean_strand;

    // 12. Test operator% with a copy of the big_strand to see if the result is the same as the loop above.

    // 13. Clean up array/vector
        DNA.clear();
    // 14. Ask the user to try again.
        cout << "Would you like to try again (y/n)?";
        cin >> rerun;

    }while(rerun == 'y' || rerun == 'Y');
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `new char(101)` - that allocates *one* char (and initializes its value to 101) , not 101 chars. I believe `new char[101]` is more inline with what you want. This problem is repeated in places like `new char(this->max_sequence+1)`, etc. Why you're not using a `std::vector<char>` is worth musing. It would solve a lot of issues, including the memory leaks I won't bother elaborating.

Comment: Off-topic -- `operator !=` is simply a 1-line function: `return !(*this == arg);` -- There is no need to rewrite `==` and then turn it inside out.

Comment: I made sure to change all the () to [ ] but a new error has popped up, occurs when reaching the user input strand removal part aka the subtraction function  : terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
Aborted (core dumped)

Comment: I know the subtraction function has logical errors in it, I am just wondering if they are causing this error or if something else is.

Comment: Why don't you simply use `std::string` instead of `new char[]`?  Or at the very least `std::vector<char>`?  If you did that, then there would be no need for a user-defined copy constructor, assignment operator (which is flawed anyway), and destructor.

Comment: Also, `operator +` and `operator -` are the same function, with one tiny difference.  Thus if `-` is not working, then `+` isn't working either.  And to add to that, you could just make both call a general function with the only difference being the operation (which could be controlled by a parameter), thus reducing your code redundancy.

Comment: Looking at your code 1) Assignment operator has memory leaks, 2) Destructor uses the wrong form of `delete`, 3) What is the loop in the `operator==` about, when you could simply use `strcmp`?  It looks like you're introducing complexity into something that is very simple.  50% to 75% of that code is not necessary.

Comment: I would love not using a user-defined copy constructor but the assignment requires that I have a user-defined one for both destructor and constructor :(. Thanks for the suggestions I'll try and simplify some code.